# Android java : How to send message from server to a specific client any time

Tags: java, android, client

I tried to send message from server to client but if i send message the client needs to connect again or println again...
So how does it work?
I tried to println again from server to client but the client wont receive it.

So how to send message to a specific client at any time.

Server:

```
package server.server.com;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server extends Thread {
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;
    static InputStream is;
    static OutputStream os;
    static byte[] buf;
    static BufferedReader reader;
    static BufferedWriter writer;
    static double ConsoleMessage;
    public static String output;
    static BufferedReader bufferedReader2;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 12345");
        }

        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 12345");

        while (true) {

            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                        clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);


                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                        clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                        bufferedReader.readLine().getBytes(
                                Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        inputStream));
                output = bufferedReader2.readLine();
                System.out.println(output);

                out.flush();
                out.close();
                inputStreamReader.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Client:

```
  client = new Socket();
  client.connect(
      new InetSocketAddress(
         "IP-ADDRESS",
         PORT),
         5000);
   in = new BufferedReader(
   new InputStreamReader(
   client.getInputStream()));
       printlng = new PrintWriter(
           client.getOutputStream());
       printlng.println(mLongitude);
       printlng.flush();

       try {
           if ((Response = in
           .readLine()) != null) {

....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html. Maybe you could take advantage of push notifications in your app.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is read always from server on client.

Comment: GCM will allow you to send messages from server to some/all devices where your app is installed. A very basic alternative is to use web services approach, but since the server doesn't know device ip, you will have to make the first contact from the phone or tablet or whatever.

Comment: But do i have to have that GCM GUI and registration?

Comment: You will have to enable Google Cloud Messaging for Android API in Google Developers Console and you will have to implement an intermediate server to store users registrations.

Comment: Basically, users start your app, they register in GCM servers and after that they send to your intermediate server some kind of ID, and part of the response they receive from GCM servers. You should store this information in databases, and according to that info, you will be able to send push notifications from your server to the devices you chose from the database. There are lot of examples in Google. If you have more doubts let me know =)

Comment: @LucianoRodríguez, then pls tell me if i could do the following:- Send my latest Chess move(eg "NF3") from my mobile via a WebService to my ASP.net application, who will then send this move to the GCM who would then send this to the mobile of Player2? isnt there anyway i could avoid GCM and send it straight to Player2's mobile? OR send my move to my ASP.net application without a Webservice?

Comment: Hi @user3833732. When you register your device to receive push notifications, you will receive one token to identify that phone. Whenever you start a game you should store the tokens of the players that are playing the chess game. Whenever one player makes a move, you should notify your ASP.net app and the ASP.net should be in charge of sending the notification to the player identified by token2.

Comment: Ok! so the Sending from ASP.net app to phone will happen via GCM, correct? And notifying the move from phone to Asp.net app via WebService? Cant avoid GCM/Webservice? no other way to send msgs between 2 phones on different networks?

Comment: No way to avoid GCM/Webservice or at least no way i know. Maybe bluetooth communication or similar, but you need to take into account that messaging applications usually work this way using XMPP server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this

Server:

```
private boolean sendMessage(final String msg, final String dstIp, final int dstPort) {

    DatagramSocket sendSocket = null;

    try {
        sendSocket = new DatagramSocket();

        final InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName(dstIp);
        final int msg_length = msg.length();
        final byte[] message1 = msg.getBytes();

        final DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(message1,
                msg_length, local, dstPort);
        sendSocket.send(sendPacket);

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {

        if (sendSocket != null) {
            sendSocket.disconnect();
            sendSocket.close();
            sendSocket = null;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Client:

```
public static void receiveMessage() {

    if ((socket == null) || socket.isClosed()) {

            socket = new DatagramSocket(BROADCAST_PORT);
            socket.setSoTimeout(5000);

        } 

     try {
            idMsgs.clear();
            while ((socket != null) && !socket.isClosed()) {
                socket.setReuseAddress(true);
                socket.setSoTimeout(10000);

                try {
                    final byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[sizepck];
                    final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
                            receiveBuffer, receiveBuffer.length);

                    socket.receive(packet);

                } catch (final SocketTimeoutException e) {

                } catch (final Throwable e) {

                }
            }

        } catch (final Throwable e1) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(TIME_RETRY);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I prefer TCP and Basically what I'm trying to do is read always from server on client.